An accurate translation for "you are what you keep"
is "es quod retines" or "es quod servas" the best way to specifically say "you are what you keep" in terms of money you don't spend/save or is there a more accurate translation? Previously I was recommended "es quod retines, non quod expendis" which is ideal, but too long. The phrase must be 20 characters or less. I appreciate the suggestion "servare est esse" but feel it is not accurate enough.
Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Are you deliberately echoing Picasso?

No, it was an independent thought. I was unaware of any correlation.

What about the verb "arceo"? "Alvus arcet et retinet quod recepit."

I would lean towards mirroring the construction of “velle est posse” and render this as “conservare est esse” or perhaps “servare est esse.”
